# Why is my player (with a collider and rigidbody) glitching through walls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm using a rigid body to move my character, it has a collider. So why does my player glitch through the walls specifically when it's going fast? My player is a capsule, I'm using a capsule collider. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often caused by： When moving too fast, Unity misses the collision, since at a new timestep your player has already passed the collision area.
A simple fix would to be either to enlarge your collider, shrink the model size, or to use continuous collision detection.

You can take a look at this Unity manual for more information.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ContinuousCollisionDetection.html

Comment: Thank you! I tried enlarging the collider and using continuous and it worked (most of the time anyway)!

Answer (score 2):

go to project setting>physics and increase(**default max depenetration velocity**)
(ex. 120)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).